# Problema con C++ y lectura de ficheros

Tags: c++, string, double

Tengo problemas al subir doubles al fichero e interpretarlos como string a la hora de cargar los datos, que carga cada vez que se entra al menu principal. Para cargar tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
fstream archivoAlumno;
double alumno[indice].calificacion[indice];
string line;

if(archivoAlumno.is_open()){
    contadorCalificacion = 0;
    while(!archivoAlumno.eof()){
        getline(archivoAlumno,line);
        alumno[contadorAlumnos].calificacion[contadorCalificacion] = stod(line);
        contadorCalificacion++;
    }       
    archivoAlumno.close();
}
```

Y para convertirlos en doubles y subirlos al fichero, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
string calif;

archivoAlumno.open(alumno[opcionAlumno].archivo);       
if(archivoAlumno.is_open()){
    for(int b=0;b<6;b++){
        calif = to_string(alumno[opcionAlumno].calificacion[b]);                        
        archivoAlumno << calif <<"\n";
    }
    archivoAlumno.close();
}
```

Cuando quiero volver a ejecutar el programa me aparece lo siguiente:

Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'invalid_argument', what(): stod

Por lo que he visto, el problema es a la hora de cargar los datos la segunda vez, la primera vez funcionan muy bien, ya que yo los escribi a mano, pero la cuando regresa al menu principal(segunda vez que carga datos) se cierra la consola, y al quererla abrir de nuevo, marca el error de arriba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude solucionar el problema. 
El problema era que, como en el link que compartio el usuario Trauma, el eof() leia la ultima linea, que resultaba ser una linea en blanco. La solucion fue la siguiente:

Yo conocia la cantidad de calificaciones que se iban a leer, ademas de que todos los alumnos iban a tener la misma cantidad de calificaciones. Aprovechando esto, inicialice un contador, y cuando ese contador llegara a 6 (el numero de materias), hiciera un `break` al `while(archivoAlumno.eof())`, para asi dejar de leer el archivo y evitar el error.